# VersionOne API team iteration target

Tags: versionone

I can't figure out how to retrieve the overriden target that has been set for a team (on an iteration):

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG3jM.png)

I'm using the query.v1 API but haven't found this information yet.

Thanks in advance!

Let me know if you need further information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for the same thing, here is the answer:

Query: `https://[your url]/VersionOne/api/Reports/Velocity`
Type: `POST`

url encoded parameters:

- `schedule`: <ID of the wanted schedule ; eg. Schedule:12345>
- `project`: <ID of the scope ; eg. Scope:12345>
- `team` [optional]: <ID of the team ; eg. Team:12345>

This will give you the result of the page "Schedule Iteration" on VersionOne.
Which is some information on the last 6 sprints (not the current one).
For each iteration you will have:

- Target estimate
- Closed estimate
- Closed estimate other
- Open estimate
- Open estimate other

For the current sprint, you can use this:
Query: `https://[your url]/VersionOne/IterationScheduling.mvc/getGridStats`
Type: `GET`

However, it uses the team filter that is set on the Iteration Scheduling page in VersionOne.